# Parsing xml in python- Having trouble writing loop

Tags: python, xml, icd

I am trying the ICD-10 XML and I want to put all of the terms into a CSV. I think that I have it working, but is there a more efficient way to loop through all of the nested  tags and to get the  and .

```
<section id="A00-A09">
    <desc>Intestinal infectious diseases (A00-A09)</desc>
    <diag>
        <name>A02</name>
        <desc>Other salmonella infections</desc>
        <includes>
            <note>infection or foodborne intoxication due to any Salmonella species other than S. typhi and S.paratyphi
            </note>
        </includes>
        <diag>
            <name>A02.0</name>
            <desc>Salmonella enteritis</desc>
            <inclusionTerm>
                <note>Salmonellosis</note>
            </inclusionTerm>
        </diag>
        <diag>
            <name>A02.1</name>
            <desc>Salmonella sepsis</desc>
        </diag>
        <diag>
            <name>A02.2</name>
            <desc>Localized salmonella infections</desc>
            <diag>
                <name>A02.20</name>
                <desc>Localized salmonella infection, unspecified</desc>
            </diag>
            <diag>
                <name>A02.21</name>
                <desc>Salmonella meningitis</desc>
            </diag>
            <diag>
                <name>A02.22</name>
                <desc>Salmonella pneumonia</desc>
            </diag>
            <diag>
                <name>A02.23</name>
                <desc>Salmonella arthritis</desc>
            </diag>
            <diag>
                <name>A02.24</name>
                <desc>Salmonella osteomyelitis</desc>
            </diag>
            <diag>
                <name>A02.25</name>
                <desc>Salmonella pyelonephritis</desc>
                <inclusionTerm>
                    <note>Salmonella tubulo-interstitial nephropathy</note>
                </inclusionTerm>
            </diag>
            <diag>
                <name>A02.29</name>
                <desc>Salmonella with other localized infection</desc>
            </diag>
        </diag>
        <diag>
            <name>A02.8</name>
            <desc>Other specified salmonella infections</desc>
        </diag>
        <diag>
            <name>A02.9</name>
            <desc>Salmonella infection, unspecified</desc>
        </diag>
    </diag>
</section>
```

This is the code that I am using.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

csvOut = open("diagnostics.csv", "wb")
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvOut, delimiter='|')

tree = ET.parse('/Users/mike/PycharmProjects/xml_sqlite_icd/Tabular.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for diag in root.iter('section'):  # Loop through every diagnostic tree
    sdesc = diag.find('desc').text.encode('utf8')
    for node in diag.iter('diag'):
        t = node.find('name').text.encode('utf8')
        desc = node.find('desc').text.encode('utf8')
        for diag1 in node.iter('diag'):  # Loop through every diagnostic tree

            temp_3 = []
            temp_4 = []
            temp3 = []
            temp4 = []


            name = diag1.find('name').text.encode('utf8')  # Extract the diag code

            desc1 = diag1.find('desc').text.encode('utf8')  # Extract the description

            for node1 in diag1.iter('inclusionTerm'):
                t3 = node1.find('note').text.encode('utf8')
                v3 = t3
                temp_3.append(v3)

            for node1 in diag1.iter('includes'):
                t4 = node1.find('note').text.encode('utf8')
                v4 = t4
                temp_4.append(v4)

            for diag2 in node1.iter('diag'):  # Loop through every diagnostic tree





                name = diag2.find('name').text.encode('utf8')  # Extract the diag code

                desc1 = diag2.find('desc').text.encode('utf8')  # Extract the description

                for node2 in diag2.iter('inclusionTerm'):
                    t_3 = node2.find('note').text.encode('utf8')
                    v_3 = t_3
                    temp3.append(v_3)

                for node2 in diag2.iter('includes'):
                    t_4 = node2.find('note').text.encode('utf8')
                    v_4 = t_4
                    temp4.append(v_4)



            csvwriter.writerow(
                [diag.attrib["id"], sdesc, t, desc, name, desc1,temp_3, temp_4,temp3, temp4, temp7])
```